# MySQL Sum(Total) and Sum(User) with ROLLUP

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, sum, rollup

I am having a little bit of trouble with a complex MySQL Query. I am trying to get 3 columns from this query. The name of the Procedure, the Site Total of each procedure, and the Physician Total (user total) for each procedure. I am linking 2 tables, `procedures` and `tbl_syn_procedure`.

There is just one condition that will get my the Physician Total (user total) and that is `procedures.phys_id = '##'`, but I am not sure how to incorporate this into the query.

I currently have a large query that gives me half of the data that I need.

```
SELECT  
  IFNULL( Synoptic, 'Total Count') AS Synoptic, Total
FROM ( 
SELECT  
  Synoptic, 
  SUM( Data ) AS Total
FROM ( 
      SELECT 
        tbl_syn_procedure.name AS 'Synoptic',
        COUNT(*) AS Data
        FROM procedures 
        JOIN tbl_syn_procedure ON 
        procedures.proc_synoptic_id = tbl_syn_procedure.name_id 
        GROUP BY procedures.proc_synoptic_id 
     ) AS stats 
  GROUP BY Synoptic WITH ROLLUP
) AS stats
```

This gives me a two column table that looks like this:

> Synoptic  -------------------------- Total
>
> APBI Device Insertion ---------- 1328
>
> MRI Guided Biopsy ------------- 71
>
> Stereotactic Biopsy ------------- 10504
>
> Total Count ---------------------- 11903

But as you can see it is missing the Physician Total (user total). If anyone could give me some advice on how to add this third column into the query.

Comment: it would be helpful to see the relevant columns of the two tables and their relationships. and do you want the Physician Total for each procedure and for each physician? because if every procedure is linked to a single physican (i'm assuming) the physician total for a procedure will be the same as the site total?

Comment: In the procedures table there is a column called phys_id. Every time the physicians enters a procedure their id gets entered into this field. So we need to count all the procedures, and also count the procedures where the procedures.phys_id = '##' (the logged in physician ID number).

For the columns of the two relevant tables...

tbl_syn_procedure has id,name,name_id,rank
procedures has a field title proc_synoptic_id which is linked to tbl_syn_procedure name_id... we are linking these tables so that we can display the name of the synoptic procedure. Display Ultrasound Biopsy and not biopsy_us

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select
count(p.proc_synoptic_id), p.proc_synoptic_id, name, num_phys_procedures
from
procedures p
inner join tbl_syn_procedure on p.proc_synoptic_id = tbl_syn_procedure.name_id
left join
(
    select count(proc_synoptic_id) as num_phys_procedures, proc_synoptic_id from procedures
    where phys_id = ##
    group by proc_synoptic_id
) phys_procedures on p.proc_synoptic_id = phys_procedures.proc_synoptic_id

group by proc_synoptic_id, name;
```

it first gets the total number of procedures then joins against a derived table `phys_procedures` that has the number of procedures for a specific physician.